# How do I assign different categories the same dummy variable in r?

Tags: r, regression, data-manipulation, dummy-variable

I am working with a data set that looks like this:

```
  ClusterID      URL               Text_Body
   0            www.text.com       texttexttexttexttext.....
   1            www.text1.com      texttexttexttexttext.....
   2            www.text2.com      texttexttexttexttext.....
   3            www.text3.com      texttexttexttexttext.....
   4            www.text4.com      texttexttexttexttext.....
   5            www.text5.com      texttexttexttexttext.....
   6            www.text6.com      texttexttexttexttext.....
   7            www.text7.com      texttexttexttexttext.....
   8            www.text8.com      texttexttexttexttext.....
```

Lets call this data set "onlinearticles". ClusterID is the cluster that an article appears in, url is the distinct url for each article, and text body is the actual article. I need to build an additional column which assigns a value of 1 to any row belonging to clusterID 0, 4, 6, and 7. Any other clusterID should have a value of 0. I need to build this column in order to do a regression tree. How can I go about building said column?

Comment: `ifelse(onlinearticles$ClusterID %in% c(0, 4, 6, 7), 1, 0)`

Comment: or `as.integer(onlinearticles$ClusterID %in% c(0, 4, 6, 7))`

Comment: If I wrote it like this:
  
        onlinearticles2<-ifelse(onlinearticles$ClusterID %in% c(0, 4, 6, 7), 1, 0) 

Would this be okay in the sense that I can now refer to onlinearticles2?

Comment: @Vindication09 almost! You just need to assign the result to a variable within `onlinearticles`. Something like: `onlinearticles$Cluster_Dummy <- ifelse(onlinearticles$ClusterID %in% c(0, 4, 6, 7), 1, 0)`